# How to delete the selected or all checkbox's in angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular5

This is my HTML where I have list of items with checkbox and global checkbox for selecting all checkboxes. Once click on delete I should be able to delete the selected or all selected checkboxes.

```
  <label (click)="delete()"> Delete these <button class="deletebutton">Delete</button></label>                 

  <ul>
      <input type="checkbox" (change)="usertodelete = $event.target.checked"/> // global checkbox to select all checkboxes

   <li *ngFor= "let user of users">
         <span>
             <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)] ="usertodelete"/>
                   <label>{{user}}</label>
         </span>
       </li>
 </ul>
```

This is my component

```
export class GroupComponent implements OnInit {
usertodelete: boolean =true;
  ngOnInit() {
      this.service.getGroupMembers().subscribe(data => {this.users = JSON.parse(data.data.items);
       } );      
  }

  delete(selectedUser:any) {  
    if(this.usertodelete) {
      this.memberstobedeleted =  this.users.slice(selectedUser);
      this.service.remove(this.memberstobedeleted);
    }
    }
```

This is my service :

```
  remove(remove:any) {
    this.body = {
      "UserId":"abf"
     }
    return this.http.put('url'+remove, this.body,{headers :new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'})}
    ).subscribe((res:Response)=>{console.log(res)});
  }
```

Comment: What was your code that wasn't working? (What did you try?)

Comment: @FrankModica i have edited my code and displaying what I have tried.When i select global checkbox its selecting all checkbox's but if i select an individual checkbox in the list its also selecting all the checkbox's. This is the issue and I should be able to delete either an individual or all by selecting global checkbox's

Comment: `slice` takes an index (not an object)

Comment: Also, you're binding each `ngModel` to the same `usertodelete` variable. You might want to have a `isChecked` property on each user object, and bind to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the model itself.

Simplification :

Say you have an array of 3  items where it has a value and `c` property for "checked" :

```
 data = [{ id: 1, c: true }, { id: 2, c: false }, { id: 3, c: true }]
```

The HTML markup would like like this :

```
<p>
    <br/>

   <input type="checkbox"  *ngFor= "let item of data"   [(ngModel)]="item.c"/>
    <input  type="button" value="clear all" (click)="delete($event)"/>

<br/>
{{ data | json}}
</p>
```

The `delete` function would like like this :

```
  delete() {
    this.data.forEach(cb => cb.c = false)
  }
```

So you're basically changing the model itself.

[**NG-run**](https://www.ng-run.com/edit/Ln0TYB8zrWapQgp2usu3)